# Calling Date Modified in CMD

Tags: command-line, cmd

Basically just attempting to create a very basic program that will display the last modified date of a file on our server. Problem is I have no idea how to write it. This is what I attempted

```
cd \\Server\Folder
msg dir
```

I also ran into the problem "CMD Does not support UNC Paths as Current Directories" when I tried to change the CD to our servers directory.

What I would like it to do is display in a dialog box the modified date of a "Text.txt" located on our server \\Server\Folder

Any and all help is appreciated

Comment: What do you mean with "program"? a batch file?

Comment: Possible duplicate [Can you browse a UNC path using a command line environment without mapping it to a network drive?](http://superuser.com/q/282963/376602). Use `pushd` instead of `cd`.

Comment: pushd worked very well to navigate to the folder. Does anyone have any knowledge on a command to just display the last modified date of a specific file in the directory?

Answer (score 1):

Next `.bat` script should work:

```
set "_folder=\\Server\Folder"
set "_filename=Text.txt"
set "_filedatetime=N/A"
pushd %_folder%
for %%G in (%_filename%) do (
  rem echo %%~tG %%~fG
  if not "%%~tG"=="" set "_filedatetime=%%~tG"
)
popd
echo file %_folder%\%_filename% date and time: %_filedatetime%
```

Note there is no *dialog box* in pure `cmd` command line interpreter, try `set /P`.

Resources:

- `SET`: [Display, set, or remove CMD environment variables](http://ss64.com/nt/set.html)
- `PUSHD`, `POPD`: [and UNC Network paths](http://ss64.com/nt/pushd.html)
- `FOR` [commands](http://ss64.com/nt/for.html)
- `~` [Parameter Extensions](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)

Comment: Thank you very much for the informative answer with resource links! I'll give it a shot